# Eignvalues of Laplacian operator and Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ an open bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $I$ un interval in $\mathbb{R}$, let $t_0 \in I$, $f\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $g\in L^2(\Omega)$. Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ the eigen values od the Laplacian operator $\Delta$, and $(e_n)_n$ the vector associates to the eigen values.
We denote 
$$u=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} [(f,e_n) \cos[(t-t_0) \sqrt{\lambda_n}] + \dfrac{(g,e_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\sin[(t-t_0)\sqrt{\lambda_n}]]e_n$$

How we can prouve that $u \in C^0(I,H^1_0(\Omega))$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} \in C^0(I,L^2(\Omega))$?

II

I undestand the answer of this question. I have an seconde question please.

How we prouve that $$\Box u = 0 \quad\mbox{in} \quad \mathcal{D}'(I^{0} \times \Omega)$$
where $\Box$ is wave operator, and $I^{0}$ is the interior od $u$.

Thank's for the help beaucause i lost.

Comment: No need to put "EDIT EDIT EDIT" in the title. You can add "EDIT" into the body of the question, indicated what was edited. Also, note that different questions should be placed in separate threads; not edited into previous questions.

Comment: the edited is in my first question. Why 
T.A.E. use it?

Comment: (1) You can ask T.A.E. in a comment to their answer; or if that doesn't help, or the explanation seems too complicated for a comment exchange (2) you can post a new question with a link to this one, saying that in such and such answer this and that was used, and you don't understand why. On a different topic, you shouldn't accept answers if you don't understand them.

Comment: It is not nice to change the question after someone answered it. Since you asked a new one already, I am going to revert the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume $\Omega$ has a smooth boundary (or something similar.) The Laplacian has a natural domain $\mathcal{D}(\Delta)=H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ because
$$
        -\Delta : \mathcal{D}(\Delta) \subset L^{2}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^{2}(\Omega)
$$
is selfadjoint and non-negative on its domain. The domain of the positive square root of $-\Delta$ is $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. Furthermore, $-\Delta$ has a complete orthonormal set of eigenfuntions $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_{n} \}_{n=0}^{\infty} \subset (0,\infty)$. By the spectral theorem,
$$
   f \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta) \iff \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty,\;\;\;
   f \in \mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta}) \iff \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty.
$$
Using Friedrichs extensions, one finds that $\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})=H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. So the above characterization of $\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})$ becomes a characterization of $H_{0}^{1}$.
Because $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ is selfadjoint, then $f(t)=e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}f_{0}$ is a continuous function from $[0,\infty)$ to $L^{2}(\Omega)$ which is given by Functional Calculus:
$$
         f(t) = e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}f_{0}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{i\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}t}(f_{0},e_{n})e_{n}.
$$
If $f_{0} \in \mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})=H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, then $f$ is a continuous function from $[0,\infty)$ to $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, and $f'(t)=\sqrt{-\Delta}f(t)=e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}(\sqrt{-\Delta}f_{0})$ is a continuous function from $[0,\infty)$ to $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Your situation is a mild variation of this.

**Your function $u$**: (Discussion added after your questions.) So you have defined $u=v+w$ where
$$
    v(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(f,e_{n})\cos((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})e_{n},
                 \;\;\; f \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\\
    w(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(g,e_{n})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\sin((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})e_{n},\;\;\; g \in L^{2}(\Omega).
$$
Both $v$ and $u$ are in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ because the Fourier coefficents with respect to the complete orthonormal set $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ in each series are square integrable:
$$
        \|v(t)\|^{2}_{L^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(f,e_{n})|^{2}\cos^{2}((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})
                \le \sum_{n} |(f,e_{n})|^{2} = \|f\|^{2},\\
      \|w(t)\|_{L^{2}}^{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|(g,e_{n})|^{2}}{\lambda_{n}}\sin^{2}((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}) \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}|(g,e_{n})|^{2}
               = \frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}\|g\|^{2}.
$$
Because $f \in H^{1}_{0}$, then the equivalent condition $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty$ holds.
This forces $v(t) \in H^{1}_{0}$ for all $t$ because
$$
    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(v(t),e_{n})|^{2}=
      \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(f,e_{n})|^{2}\sin^{2}((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(f,e_{n})|^{2} < \infty.
$$
Similarly, $w(t) \in H^{1}_{0}$ for all $t$ because $g\in L^{2}$ and you're dividing the Fourier coefficients of $g$ by $\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}$, which puts the result in $H^{1}_{0}$. So everything is properly defined and $u(t) \in H^{1}_{0}$ for all $t$.

As I pointed out before, $h \in H^{1}_{0}$ iff $h\in\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})$, and, in that case,
$$
               \|h\|^{2}_{H^{1}_{0}}=\|h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}+\|\nabla h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}
      = \|h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}+\|\sqrt{-\Delta}h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+\lambda_{n})|(f,e_{n})|^{2}.
$$
In fact, for $h \in L^{2}$, the sum on the right is finite iff $h \in H^{1}_{0}$. To shorten the expressions, let $s_{n}(t)=\sin((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})$ and $c_{n}(t)=\cos((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})$. What you've got is
$$
\begin{align}
      \|u(t)-u(t')\|_{H^{1}_{0}}
   & \le\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+\lambda_{n})|(f,e_{n})|^{2}|c_{n}(t)-c_{n}(t')|^{2}\right]^{1/2} \\
   & +\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1+\lambda_{n}}{\lambda_{n}}|(g,e_{n})|^{2}|s_{n}(t)-s_{n}(t')|^{2}\right]^{1/2}.
\end{align}
$$
The sums are absolutely and uniformly convergent with respect to $t$, $t'$ because $f \in H^{1}_{0}$ and $g\in L^{2}$. It follows that the above is continuous in $t,t'$. So $u : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^{1}_{0}$ is a continuous vector function. And when you take a derivative of $u$, you end up with a continuous function $u' : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow L^{2}$. The reduced regularlity is because of the added $\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}$ which appears in the derived sums. I'll let you work out the details.

**Your New Modifications:** The new mention of $\Box$ requires that you be able to take two time derivatives. This can be done if $f\in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$ and $g \in \mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})=H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. If $f$, $g$ are as stated, then taking two time derivatives gives the same result as applying $-\Delta$ (both multiply the n-th Fourier coefficient by $\lambda_{n}$.) The expression $\Box$ is now interpreted in terms of a derivative of a vector function in $t$ and in terms of an operator $-\Delta$, which is more subtle than classical derivatives. So $\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}u(t) = \Delta u(t)$ in this operator language, where $u : [t_{0},\infty)\rightarrow L^{2}(\Omega)$ is a vector function whose value lies in the domain of $-\Delta$ for all $t > 0$ so that $-\Delta u(t)$ makes sense, provided $f \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$ and $g\in H_{0}^{1}$.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, please, how you use Friedrichs extensions?

Comment: Without getting too far into that, you can just look at $\|\nabla f\|^{2}=(-\Delta f,f)=\|\sqrt{-\Delta}f\|^{2}$ for $f \in H^{2}\cap H^{1}_{0}$. That's essentially all you need to see that the domain of $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ is $H_{0}^{1}$.

Comment: But $g$ in in $L^2(\Omega)$ not $H^1(\Omega)$, so there is an problem for the second therm of $u$. No?

Comment: When you divide $(g,e_{n})$ by $\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}$ and form the Fourier series, the result function is in $H^{1}_{0}$ because of the characterization of $H^{1}_{0}$ as $\mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})$.

Comment: Please, help me beaucause i don't understand this last point. Why $(g,e_n) \in H^1_0$?

Comment: Can you explicit more this last point, please.

Comment: $f \in \mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})=H^{1}_{0}$ iff $\sum |\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(f,e_{n})|^{2}< \infty$. Check this condition for $f = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}(g,e_{n})\sin(\cdots)e_{n}$ to see that $f \in H^{1}_{0}$. Note: you know $\sum_{n}|(g,e_{n})|^{2}=\|g\|_{L^{2}} < \infty$.

Comment: I found the follow proof: to prouve that $u\in C^0(I,H^1_0(\Omega)$, let $t_1 \in I$ and $(t_j)$ include on $I$ such that $t_j --> t_1$. Then, $$||u_{t_j}-u_{t_1}||^2_{H^1_0} \leq 2 \sum_{n\geq1} (\lambda_n|(f,e_n)|^2 |\cos[(t_j-t_0)\sqrt{\lambda_n}]-\cos[(t_1-t_0)\sqrt{\lambda_n}]|^2|^2 + |(g,e_n)|^2|\sin[(t_j-t_0)\sqrt{\lambda_n}]-\sin[(t_1-t_0)\sqrt{\lambda_n}]|^2)$$ and we conclude by the convergence domine to prouve that $\lim_{j->+\infty}||u_{t_j}-u_{t_1}||_{H^1_0}=0$

Comment: but i don't understand how they write $||u_{t_j}-u_{t_1}||^2_{H^1_0}$ inthis way, and his conclusions. Are you understand this last proof? Please

Comment: Look at my previous comment where I point out that $\|\nabla f\|=\|\sqrt{-\Delta}f\|$, which is part of the $H^{1}_{0}$ norm. More explicitly, $\|f\|_{H_{0}^{1}}^{2}=\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2}+\|\nabla f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}=\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2}+\|\sqrt{-\Delta}f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}$.

Comment: Your proof is more interessant. Last question please. Who is $f_0$ in my problem? Thank's for the help.

Comment: I've fleshed out the last part with much more detail. This problem is worth understanding because the machinery of Sobolev spaces is designed for, and ideally suited for it.

Comment: Thak's for details, i understand the all, but i don't understand this point:$$
               \|h\|^{2}_{H^{1}_{0}}=\|h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}+\|\nabla h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}
      = \|h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}+\|\sqrt{-\Delta}h\|^{2}_{L^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+\lambda_{n})|(f,e_{n})|^{2}.
$$ why you write the norme like an sum? it must be an intergral. No?

Comment: The sum and the integral expressions are equivalent for $H^{1}_{0}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Can you help me please fot my secon question? I edit my first post.

Comment: I found this solution: let $\psi \in C^{\infty}_0(I^0 \times \Omega)$, we have $$\langle \Delta u,\psi \rangle = \displaystyle\int_I \langle u,\Delta \psi(t,.)\rangle dt = \displaystyle\int_I \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n(t) \langle e_n,\Delta \psi(t,.)\rangle dt$$ then $$=\displaystyle\int_I \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n(t) \langle \Delta e_n,\psi(t,.)\rangle dt = \displaystyle\int_I \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n(t) (-\lambda_n)\langle e_n,\psi(t,.)\rangle dt$$

Comment: But i don't understand any thinigs in this proof. How we write de dualyty croche $\langle .,. \rangle$ heare? Can you more explicite your proof please, please. Thank you for all.

Comment: Are you saying you have a solution and you want me to look at something? Or are you asking about something from another source? And what is that you're asking? By the way, the derivatives in $t$ of $u(t)$ exist in a strong sense under the conditions I stated, and can't be weakened in general.

Comment: My question is, in the answer, you tell why $\Box u$ make a sens. But, why $\Box u = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega)$? how we can prouve it? thank you

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are smooth enough, then you'll get uniform convergence of the series, and that will give you joint differentiability in $t$ and $x$. Otherwise, as you suggest, a weak solution may be in order. If you think about it, the Physics equations are derived from integral (averaging) properties; and only by assuming additional regularity do you get pointwise equations. So the integral properties are--in some sense--good enough.

Comment: So we must write the solution who's in my poste? There is no other simple solution to prouve that $\Box u = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega)$?

Comment: Have you a complete proof to prouve the identité $\Box u = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega)$? If yes can you post it please. Thabk you

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by $\Box$. This is the same problem as what you mean by $\Delta$. If the functions are smooth enough, then the meaning is classical. My meaning is $\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}u(t)-\Delta u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is a vector valued function of $t$ with values in $\mathcal{D}(\Delta)$. And $\Delta$ is a selfadjoint extension of the classical operator. This is typical for time evolution systems. Precisely what do you mean and want?

Comment: Why $\Box u =\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + \Delta u$ is equal to 0 in the space $\mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega)$?

Comment: You do understand that $\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}u(t)+\Delta u(t)=0$ in the sense that I have described, right? Is that the issue, or this an issue of interpreting everything in terms of $U(t,x)=(u(t))(x)$ and trying to define $\Box$ on such a space?

Comment: So have you an solution please? Because the solution who i propose is not complete and i don't know how i complete it

Comment: I'll add more, but can't until later.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I'm waiting

Comment: @T.A.E.: the OP seems [to be looking for you](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809964/question-to-t-a-e).

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this about a weak solution. Editing is becoming slow, so I'm adding another post.

I'm assuming that $f \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$ and that $g \in \mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})=H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$. That way, $u(t)$ as you have defined is a continuously differentiable vector function of $t$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$. And,
$$
\begin{align}
    (-\Delta)u(t) & =(-\Delta)
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(f,e_{n})\cos((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})
 + \frac{(g,e_{n})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\sin((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})\right]e_{n} \\
   & =
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(f,e_{n})\cos((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})
 + \frac{(g,e_{n})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\sin((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})\right]\lambda_{n}e_{n} \\
   & =
     -\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(f,e_{n})\cos((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})
 + \frac{(g,e_{n})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\sin((t-t_{0})\sqrt{\lambda_{n}})\right]e_{n}\;.
\end{align}
$$
All of the sums involved are convergent in $L^{2}$ because of the assumptions on $f$, $g$. Suppose that $\psi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(I\times \Omega)$. Then $t\mapsto \psi(x,t)$ can be considered to be an infinitely differentiable function of $t$ with values in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Using the inner-product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $L^{2}(\Omega)$, the function $t\mapsto (u(t),\psi(\cdot,t))$ is a twice continuously function of $t$ which is compactly supported in $I$. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
  (\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}u(t),\psi)
      &=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}u(t),\psi)
        -(\frac{d}{dt}u(t),\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi) \\
  (u(t),\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\psi)
      &=\frac{d}{dt}(u(t),\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi)
        -(\frac{d}{dt}u(t),\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi)
\end{align}
$$
Integrating over $I$ then gives
$$
     \int_{I}(\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}u,\psi)\,dt=-\int_{I}(\frac{d}{dt}u,\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi)\,dt = \int_{I}(u,\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\psi)\,dt.
$$
For fixed $t$, one can consider $\psi(t,\cdot)$ to be a vector in $\mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$, and, because $-\Delta$ is selfadjoint on $L^{2}(\Omega)$,
$$
        (\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}u(t),\psi)=(\Delta u(t),\psi)=(u(t),\Delta\psi). 
$$
Combining these last two equations gives
$$
        \int_{I}(u,\Delta\psi)\,dt = \int_{I}(u,\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\psi)\,dt
$$
In other words,
$$
          (u,\Box \psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}=0,\;\;\; \psi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(I\times\Omega).
$$
Therefore $T_{u} \in \mathcal{D}'(I^{0}\times\Omega)$ defined by $T_{u}(\psi)=(u,\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}$ satisfies the weak equation $\Box T_{u}=0$.

**You've added more to your question.** Assuming $F=F(t)$ is in $C^{0}(I,L^{2}(\Omega))$, you must now solve for $u(t) \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ such that
$$
           \Box u = F,\;\;\; u(0)=u'(0)=0.
$$
This $u$ can be found by assuming the separation of variables solution $u(t)=\sum_{n}a_{n}(t)e_{n}$. Formally, the equation reduces to
$$
   \sum_{n}(a_{n}''+\lambda_{n}a_{n})e_{n} = \sum_{n}(F,e_{n})e_{n},\\
        a_{n}(0)=a_{n}'(0)=0.
$$
So the coefficients $a_{n}$ satisfy and ODE
$$
             a_{n}''(t)+\lambda_{n}a_{n}(t) = (F,e_{n}),\;\; a_{n}(0)=a_{n}'(0)=0.
$$
The function $(F,e_{n})$ is an inner-product in $L^{2}(\Omega)$, and $(F,e_{n})$ is a continuous function of $t$ because $t\mapsto F(t)\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ is continuous. The solution I find by variation of parameters is the same as yours:
$$
\begin{align}
        a_{n} & =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}t)\int_{0}^{t}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}s)(F,e_{n})|_{s}\,ds \\
      & +\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}t)\int_{0}^{t}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}s)(F,e_{n})|_{s}\,ds \\
    & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\int_{0}^{t}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}(t-s))(F,e_{n})|_{s}\,ds.
\end{align}
$$
The coefficients $a_{n}(t)$ are twice continuously differentiable and satisfy
$$
    |\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}a_{n}|^{2} \le \int_{0}^{t}|\sin(\cdots)|^{2}\,ds\int_{0}^{t}|(F,e_{n})|^{2}\,ds.
$$
So, as a crude estimate, $|\sin(\cdots)|\le 1$ and
$$
     \sum_{n}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}a_{n}|^{2} \le t\int_{0}^{t}\sum_{n}|(F,e_{n})|^{2}\,ds
   = t \int_{0}^{t}\|F(s)\|^{2}\,ds
$$
Therefore, $u(t)=\sum_{n}a_{n}e_{n}$ is in $H^{1}_{0}$ for each $t \ge 0$. It's not too hard show that $t \mapsto u(t)\in H_{0}^{1}$ is continuous. Taking a derivative with respect to $t$ of $u$ leads to sum where the $1/\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}$ disappears, and $t\mapsto u'(t)\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ is continuous.

**Note:** The previous arguments used to show that you have a weak solution no longer work because the assumptions you have given are not enough to guarantee that $t\mapsto u(t)$ is a twice continuously differentiable vector function. However, it is still the case that $\Box T_{u} = F$ in the weak sense, which adds an interesting and important twist to the problem. The argument is still simple, just a little different. If $\psi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(I^{0}\times \Omega)$, then $\Box(a_{n}(t)e_{n}(x))=(F,e_{n})_{L^{2}(\Omega)}e_{n}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
        (\Box T_{u})(\psi) = \int_{I^{0}\times\Omega}u\Box \psi\,dx\,dt 
  & = (u,\Box\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)} \\
  & =(\sum_{n}a_{n}(t)e_{n}(x),\Box\psi(t,x))_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)} \\
  & = \sum_{n}(a_{n}e_{n},\Box\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)} \\
  & = \sum_{n}(\Box(a_{n}e_{n}),\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)} \\
  & = \sum_{n}((F,e_{n})_{L^{2}(\Omega)}e_{n},\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}\\
  & = (\sum_{n}(F,e_{n})_{L^{2}(\Omega)}e_{n},\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}\\
  & = (F,\psi)_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}.
\end{align}
$$
Of course, this assumes you know that the eigenfunctions $e_{n}(x)$ are smooth (which they are) and vanish at the boundary of the smooth region $\Omega$ (which they do.)

**Justification of interchange of sum and inner-product:** You have edited the question again, to ask about the justification for going from line (2) to (3) of the multi-line equation above. All you need to do in order to establish that equality is to show that $\sum_{n} a_{n}(t)e_{n}(x)$ converges in $L^{2}(I\times\Omega)$. First notice that $(a_{n}e_{n},a_{k}e_{k})_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}=0$ for $n\ne k$, which follows from the orthogonality of $\{ e_{n} \}$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. So, look at
$$
    \|a_{n}e_{n}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(I\times\Omega)}=\|a_{n}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(I)}\|e_{n}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}=\|a_{n}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(I)}
$$
To get what you want, all you need to show is that $\sum_{n}\|a_{n}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(I)} < \infty$. From the crude estimate given above,
$$
     \sqrt{\lambda_{1}}\sum_{n}|a_{n}(t)|^{2} \le \sum_{n}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}a_{n}(t)|^{2} \le 
    t \int_{0}^{t}\|F(s)\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\,ds.
$$
The integral over $I$ of the right side is finite; so that gives you all you need to get convergence in $L^{2}(I\times\Omega)$ of the orthogonal series $u = \sum_{n}a_{n}(t)e_{n}(x)$.

Comment: Your proof is exellente. I understand all the steps. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, i have a last question

Comment: Let $\Omega$ an open bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $I$ an interval on $\mathbb{R}$, $t_0 \in I$. Let $F=(F_t)\in C^0(I,L^2(\Omega))$. There exist a unique$u\in C^0(I,H^1_0(\Omega)) \cap C^1(I^0,L^2(\Omega))$ such that $$\Box u= F \quad \mbox{dans} \mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega), \quad u_{t_0}=0,\quad u^{(1)}_{t_0}=0$$ and this solution is $$u_t=\sum_{n\geq 1}(\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^t\dfrac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n} (t-s))}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} F_n(s)ds)e_n$$, where $$F_t=\sum_{n\geq 1}F_n(t)e_n$$

Comment: My problem is to prouve that this u satisfies $u\in C^0(I,H^1_0(\Omega)) \cap C^1(I^0,L^2(\Omega))$ ans $\Box u= F$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega)$. Help me please.

Comment: Assume the solution is found by separation of values as $\sum_{n=1}F_{n}(t)e_{n}$ and arrive at $F_{n}''(t)+\lambda_{n}F_{n}=(F,e_{n})$. This gives one ODE for each coefficient--you'll need initial conditions $F_{n}(0)=F_{n}'(0)=0$. The verification should follow the same basic steps that I outlined for you.

Comment: Can you explain me this technical more, please, and these is my last question, or if you have a book where we find the proof of the two points: $u\in C^0(I,H^1_0(\Omega))\cap C^1(I^0,L^2(\Omega))$ and the second point $\Box u = F$ in \mathcal{D}'(I^0 \times \Omega)$ to understand this non-homogeneous case. I don't know this technical. Thank's for the help.

Comment: If $f \in L^{2}$, then $g=\sum_{n}\frac{(f,e_{n})}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}e_{n} \in \mathcal{D}(\sqrt{-\Delta})=H_{0}^{1}$ with $\sqrt{-\Delta}g=f$, and $h=\sum_{n}\frac{(f,e_{n})}{\lambda_{n}}e_{n} \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$ with $(-\Delta)h=f$. So, for any $f \in L^{2}$, you can easily show that $u\in C^{0}(I,H_{0}^{1})\cap C^{1}(I^{0},L^{2})$ just by looking at the coefficients of the $e_{n}$.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. In this last case, the coefficient of $e_n$ is $\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^t \dfrac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n} (t-s))}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} F_n(s)ds$ with $F_t=\sum_{n\geq 1} F_n(t) e_n$ where $F_t\in C^0(I,L^2(\Omega))$. What's your argument to conclude that $u \in C^0(I,H^1_0) \cap C^1(I^0,L^2)$?

Comment: And how you arrive at $F''_n+\lambda_n = (F,e_n)$? Help me please

Comment: remark. And in my last problem, there is no $f$ and no $g$. and there is no $(E_n,e_n)$. Thank's for more explains please.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are names so that I talk about the general principle. I've added more. The point is this: $\sum_{n} c_{n}e_{n}(x) \in H_{0}^{1}$ iff $\sum_{n}|\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}c_{n}|^{2}< \infty$.

Comment: Thank's for the help, thank you very much. I don't understand, how the equation is formally reduced to $\sum_n a ''_n + \lambda_n a_n)e_n = \sum_n F_n e_n$? and how the term whith $\cos$ vanish in the expression of $a_n$?

Comment: $\Box(a_{n}(t)e_{n}(x))=a_{n}''(t)e_{n}+\lambda_{n}e_{n}$ because $(-\Delta)e_{n}=\lambda_{n}e_{n}$. And $F(t)=\sum_{n}(F(t),e_{n})e_{n}$ is an $L^{2}$ expansion with time varying coefficients $(F,e_{n})$.

Comment: Please, why $$(\sum_n a_n(t) e_n(x),\Box \psi (t,x))_{L^2} = \sum_n (a_n e_n , \Box \psi)_{L^2}$$ What's the justification for this?

Comment: Please can you help me for my last question? Thank's for all.

Comment: I added more for you.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Please, can you help me in this last problem:

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and let $g\in L^2(\Omega )$. 
 Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be the eigenvalues of the Laplacian operator $\Delta$, and $(e_n)_n$ the eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalues.
There exist a unique $u=(u_t)\in C^0([0,+\infty [,L^2(\Omega ))$ that solves the problem
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}−\Delta u=0 ,\in D′(]0,+\infty [\times \Omega),\quad u_0=g,\quad u_t\in H^1_0(\Omega )$$
with $u_t=\sum^{+\infty }_{n=1}e^{−λ_nt}(g,e_n) e_n$

Comment: My question is how we prove that
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}−\Delta u=0 ,\in D′(]0,+\infty [\times \Omega) ?$$

Comment: I tried this:

$$\Delta u(t)=\Delta \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} [e^{-\lambda_n t} (g,e_n)e_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda_n t} (g,e_n) (-\lambda_n) e_n$$

Let $\psi \in C^{\infty}_c(I \times \Omega)$; We have: 
$$(\dfrac{d}{dt} u(t),\psi)=-(u(t),\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial t})$$
My problem is to conclude that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I \times \Omega)$.

Comment: Can you help me please

Comment: You're probably confused by the added negative in $t$. But remember that, in a distributional sense, $\frac{\partial T_{u}}{\partial t}(\psi)=-T_{u}(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t})$. You didn't have those problems with second derivatives, but it's critical to remember the negative for odd order derivatives. Then everything will work out for you: one negative from integration by parts matches one negative for the distributional derivative.

Comment: $$\langle \dfrac{d}{dt} u(t) , \psi \rangle_{D',D} = - \langle u(t) , \dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \rangle_{D',D}$$ But my problem is to conclude.

Comment: How we can conclude, and please how we can prouve that $u\in C^0([0,+\infty[,L^2(\Omega)$? And $\forall l \in \mathbb{N}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, u^{(l)}_t \in C^0(]0,+\infty[, H^k(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega))$?

Comment: The $D'$, $D$ pairing you show is the definition of distributional derivative for the distribution $u$. It's exactly what I wrote in the previous comment. Please check the definition for the derivative of a distribution.

Comment: Ah! i understand. $u(t)$ isn't an distribution, it only represent an distribution.

Comment: So, we have to calculate the inner product $(u(t),\psi)_{L^2}$? For this we use the intergration by parts. Bit how we can do this integration by part with $\dfrac{du}{dt}$?

Comment: Please, help me to understand this last point.

Comment: How we can conclude, and please how we can prouve that u∈C^0([0,+∞[,L^2(Ω)? And ∀l∈N,∀k∈N,u^(l)_t∈C^0(]0,+∞[,H^k(Ω)∩H^1_0(Ω))?