# eignvalues of Laplacian operator and distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $I$ an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, let $t_0 \in I$, $f\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $g\in L^2(\Omega)$. Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ the eigenvalues of the Laplacian operator $\Delta$, and $(e_n)_n$ the vector associates to the eigenvalues.

We denote 
$$u=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} [(f,e_n) \cos[(t-t_0) \sqrt{\lambda_n}] + \dfrac{(g,e_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\sin[(t-t_0)\sqrt{\lambda_n}]]e_n$$

such that $u \in C^0(I,H^1_0(\Omega))$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} \in C^0(I,L^2(\Omega))$.

How we can prove that $$\Box u = 0 \quad\text{in}\quad \mathcal{D}'(I^{0} \times \Omega)$$
where $\Box$ is wave operator, ($\Box u = \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \Delta u$, and $I^{0}$ is the interior of the interval $I$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: each term in the sum satisfies the wave equation, so it's enough to prove that the sum converges in $\mathcal D'$ - but it converges in $L^2$ (I hope :), so it's OK

Comment: I have this duscussion in the edit of my topic, on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805229/edit-eignvalues-of-laplacian-operator-and-sobolev-spaces/805558#805558

Comment: in case my comment was too brief/unclear: 1) convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in $\mathcal D'$, 2) $\Box$ (as any linear diff.op.) is continuous as a map $\mathcal D'\to\mathcal D'$, and thus 3) if $u=\sum_n u_n$ converges in $L^2$ and $\Box u_n=0$ (in the sense of distributions - though your $u_n$'s are actually smooth) for all $n$'s then $\Box u=0$ in $\mathcal D'$.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. I have a big problem with this problem

Comment: I think I missed this before. What do you mean by $\mathcal{D}'$?

Comment: I was thinking you just wanted to interpret the function on a $I\times \Omega$. You probably mean a distributional solution. Then that makes sense in terms of your integrals. The integral identities apply when using $C^{\infty}_{0}$ functions; so you should be okay. As you did, just switch from integral to inner-product. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: $\mathcal{D}'$ is the space of distributions.

Comment: So have you an solution please? Because the solution who i propose is not complete and i don't know how i complete it

Comment: Can you help me please